# How to remove the visual vertical bars for Python files?

Tags: python, display

I am using Emacs 27.2 on a Mac OS with Steve Purcell's configuration. I have got some visual vertical bars for Python files. How can they be removed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Purcell's configuration, but you can disable that with a simple setting `(setq display-fill-column-indicator nil)` placed at the end of your init file - or search your configuration file for the item `display-fill-column-indicator` and comment it.

Note this may be useful warning for/when you write long lines and breaking Python standards.